# Text animation over slide show using "cycle-after" for cycle2

Tags: jquery, slideshow, jquery-cycle2

I'm trying to make text `slide` or `fade in` from being hidden after the slideshow has completed transitioning to the next slide. An example is the slideshow on [this website](http://littleboogaweezin.com/).

I am trying to do this using the "cycle-after" event the `cycle-2` [API has specified](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/), however I am not well-versed in jQuery and I am not sure of what event handler code to place within the event to achieve this effect, i.e.:

```
$( '#mySlideshow' ).on( 'cycle-after', function(event, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag) {
    // I'm not sure what to put here to make this effect//
});
```

I know I need to make divs with the text and plug them into the jQuery, I just don't know the correct code to achieve that effect.

Also, I want the text to look similar to that of the website I have previously mentioned, which is why I am not using the overlay feature in `cycle2`.

Here is my code so far:

**HTML:**

```
<script type id="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2    /jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type id="text/javascript" src="https://malsup.github.io/min/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div class="cycle-slideshow"
data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz
data-cycle-timeout=4000
data-cycle-slides="> a"
data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true"
 >

<div class="cycle-prev"></div>
<div class="cycle-next"></div>

<a href="">
<img src="http://i1255.photobucket.com/albums/hh628/prestonhitzler/moss1resize_zps6b660b8e.jpg" />
</a>

<a href="">
<img src="http://i1255.photobucket.com/albums/hh628/prestonhitzler/moss2resize_zps2fb527e4.jpg" />
</a>

<a href="">
<img src="http://i1255.photobucket.com/albums/hh628/prestonhitzler/moss3resize_zpsffdcdbd2.jpg" />
</a>

<a href="">

<img src="http://i1255.photobucket.com/albums/hh628/prestonhitzler/moss4resize_zps8d09372f.jpg" />
</a> 

<a href="">
<img src="http://i1255.photobucket.com/albums/hh628/prestonhitzler/moss5resize_zpscb87b4ed.jpg" />
</a>

</div><!-- slideshow -->
</div><!-- container -->


</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">

.cycle-slideshow, .cycle-slideshow * {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;  
}
.cycle-slideshow {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://malsup.github.com/images/spinner.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
.cycle-slideshow img:first-child {
    position: static; 
    z-index: 100;
}
.cycle-slideshow img { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    padding: 0; 
    display: block;
}
.cycle-slideshow a{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.cycle-prev, .cycle-next { 
position: absolute; 
top: 35%; 
width: 6.68%;
height: 23%;
opacity: 0.3;
z-index: 800; 
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cycle-prev{
  background: url('http://i1255.photobucket.com/albums/hh628/prestonhitzler/Arrow- Back1_zps9f5ab580.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;
  left: 0;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.cycle-next{
background: url('http://i1255.photobucket.com/albums/hh628/prestonhitzler/Arrows-       Forward1_zps598390d7.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;
  right: 0;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.cycle-prev:hover, .cycle-next:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
 </style>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to cycle a set of containers.

```
<div class='cycle-wrap'>
    <div class='slide'></div>
    <div class='slide'></div>
</div>
```

Inside each of the containers you will place your image, and the overlay content.

```
<div class='slide'>
    <img src='' />
    <div class='content'></div>
</div>
```

These will need to positioned like so:

```
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.slide > img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; //these numbers can obviously be more specific dimensions
}

.slide > .content
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .3s;
    z-index: 10;
}

.slide.cycle-slide-active > .content
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .3s;
}
```

Now whatever you put inside your .content for each slide will be faded in on whatever slide cycle adds the .cycle-slide-active class to.  No additional jQuery necessary what-so-ever.

To make the cycle plugin attach to the .slide elements change how you create cycle to indicate that it should cycle .slide:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-slides=".slide">
```

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks for the reply. I am having trouble implementing your method. When I do, my slideshow stops being a slide show and the images display block, one on top of the other. I've posted the code I am working with in my original post.

Comment: The .slide class needs to be positioned absolutely, top: 0, left: 0.  I've adjusted me post to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks again, Ben. It works great! I will say for anyone who reads this, I thought the code wasn't working until I changed the `transition` time to a longer amount of time. I was between `4s` and `6s` before it was behaving the way I wanted it to.